# Get month name from number in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table with a column `month`(`integer`). In this column I store values like `1, 2, .. 12`.
But I have to show the month *name*.

Ex:
If the value is `1` I need to display `jan`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Basically what @small_duck already posted, but a couple of improvements:

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (4::text, 'MM'), 'TMmon')
```

- A plain cast to text `4::text` is enough, no need for `to_char(..)`.
- Question asks for lower case "jan", there is a [template pattern](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) for that: `mon`.
- If you want to localize the output, prefix the template with the [modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) `TM`.

Answer (score 7):

There might be a quicker answer, but it seems to be possible by:

- Turning your int into a string
- Reading that string as a timestamp
- Displaying the month of the timestamp.

For example:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(to_char(4, '999'), 'MM'), 'Mon')
```

returns 'Apr'.

You can turn it into a function:

```
create function to_month(integer) returns varchar as
$$
    select to_char(to_timestamp(to_char($1, '999'), 'MM'), 'Mon');
$$ language sql
```

and use it throughout your code.

```
select to_month(month_column) from mytable
```

Comment: Hey - any idea why a very similar implementation would have difficulties interpreting the entire month name correctly?

YEAR(DM.DATE) || TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(to_Char(
  case 
   when 
    month(DM.DATE)+1>12 then 1 
    else month(DM.TM_DIM_KY_DTE)+1 end
   ,'99'), 'MM'), 'Mon')

Goal was to have the current year plus one month after the current month, so Nov 2012 should be Dec 2012 like '2012Dec'. For some reason certain letters get returned as numbers like Dec = 4ec or Jan = 1721395an