# PostgreSQL misinterpreting characters as numbers after casting

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, casting, netezza

I have been following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094392/get-month-name-from-number-in-postgresql) to convert a date to month name. However, when I get a shifting window of two months, the second month's name gets fragmented in the interpretation of some letters.

```
FISCAL_YEAR 
        || TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(to_Char(month(DATE_VAR),'999'), 'MM'), 'Month'
        || TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(to_Char(
        case 
            when 
                month(DATE_VAR)+1>12 then 1 
                else month(DATE_VAR)+1 end
            ,'999'), 'MM'), 'Month'))
```

The outcome would ideally be `2016DecemberJanuary`, but it returns something like `2016December1721395anuar1` or `2016May17211181une`.

It appears the issue is in the logic that accounts the shift from Dec to Jan. What causes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select to_char(now(),'January');` returns something like `2457729anuar6` because

> J - Julian Day (integer days since November 24, 4714 BC at midnight UTC)
>   .
>  
>   Y - last digit of year

[Link.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

You need to quote strings in the format string to prevent interpreting it as the placeholders: `select to_char(now(),'YY, "January"');`